# Single Connection Multiple Databases TypeORM

Tags: javascript, multiple-databases, node.js-typeorm

I'm trying to connect to multiple databases from single connection using typeORM in javascript. There's a way doing it using typescript

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column} from "typeorm";

@Entity({ database: "secondDB" })
export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    firstName: string;

    @Column()
    lastName: string;

}
```

I tried to replicate this in javascript like this:

```
const { EntitySchema } = require("typeorm");

const userSchema = {
   name: "User",
   database: "secondDB",
    columns: {
      id: { 
        primary: true, 
        type: "int", 
        generated: true 
     },
      firstName: { 
        type: "text"
     },
      lastName: { 
        type: "text"
     },

 }

 module.exports = new EntitySchema(userSchema);
```

This doesn't seem to switch databases, Is there an equivalent way of doing this in javascript. I'm connecting to a postgresDB

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I worked with type-orm, but I know that a single connection with multiple databases at the time was only supported for MySQL and MsSQL databases.

> In this document: https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/multiple-connections.
> It states that "Using multiple databases in a single connection" "this feature is supported only in mysql and mssql databases".

[link to relevant github issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/6333)